# php why there isn't a \jsonUnserializable interface with jsonUnserialize method?

Tags: php

As there is a `\JsonSerializable` interface with a `jsonSerialize` method, why there isn't the opposite `\jsonUnserializable` interface with `jsonUnserialize` method?

Is there any OFFICIAL reason about this? Some OFFICIAL debates taken somewhere? Some OFFICIAL notes?

It seems at first hand logical to add also a `\JsonUnserializable` interface, so I'm asking myself why it doesn't exist. I'm very curious!

Comment: If anything, that very interface should implement the unserialize method. Another interface for that purpose would not make sense. (Check Serializable - jdk 1.7, same idea applies)

Comment: Yes, ever at first hand... But I may want to serialize an object but not unserialize it, as it may be sufficient to have the array representation...

Comment: as a stop-gap measure, i have a standard static constuctor for all relevant business objects classes, something like `Foo::constructFromJson($json)`, where i implement the deserialization intricacies, as needed. Not ideal, but works for now.

Comment: Yes, it may work. But it seems like a trick... Anyway yes, it is a possible solution :)

Comment: @Sebas PHP had already implemented the `JsonSerializable` interface before the discussion of an unserializable counterpart was raised. Adding a method to the deployed interface could not be done, because it would break existing interface implementations. See specifically http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=143679968330980&w=2

Comment: Possible is possible in a major version (PHP `7.2`)... But I'm not sure it is the good answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From PHP wiki

> PHP RFC: JsonSerializable New Interface method Proposal :
>
> Due to discussions, it seems the best way to implement this method is
> with a new function.

```
$user = json_decode_to_class($json, User::class);
```

More information here :

> https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jsonserializable

The complete discussion can be found here :

> http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=143679379628977&w=2

Comment: The RFC basically propose to break existing interface by adding a method that will break older code not implementing it. Or it would require some default method implementation, but there is no such thing in PHP. I think this is why this RFC is stale right now. Yet another questionable design choice with PHP. This `JsonSerializable` interface is unfortunately of very narrow purpose and cannot be sanely evolved. Just a dead-end.